# Is a Lipschitz continuous function always differentiable?

Tags: continuity

> Lipchitz condition: $f:R→R$ is called Lipschitz continuous if there
> exists a $K>0$ such that, for all real $x_1$ and $x_2$, $|f(x_1 
>  )-f(x_2 )|≤K|x_1-x_2 |$.

Is every function satisfying the Lipchitz condition differentiable?

Comment: What about the absolute value function?

Comment: No, but they are differentiable almost everywhere (Rademacher theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample is $$y=|x|$$. This function is not differentiable at $x=0$. However, it is Lipschitz continuous, since $|y(x_1)-y(x_2)|\le |x_1-x_2|$.